Movie about two teenage groups, one of these groups where fans of Prince
The recent pass away of Prince made me think about a movie I watched as kid, about 20 years ago.
I watched it on TV and I'm quite sure it was from the 80s.
It was most probably American.
The plot involved a group of teenagers on what I think was a kind of summer camp, where there was a rivalry between two groups. One of them consisted of fans of Prince. I think the other one supported Michael Jackson and they were arguing who was the real King Of Pop. I think the leader of the Prince gang wore a bandana on his head, in a style similar to those presented here.
Both groups were supposed to perform a task that I think was some kind of a construction work, perhaps house renovation. They were reluctant initially, but eventually decided to do it. I don't remember if both groups were rivaling on this or they united first and then done the work together. I remember that when they started the work a lively 80s hit started to play. I was sure that it was Starship's We Built This City, but after doing some research on the list of movies where this song was used it seems that it's not the case.

Did they actually use the term "King of Pop"? Because Jackson didn't start using that descriptor til 1991. They wouldn't have used it in the 80's. It will help establish release date, thanks.

@Sara M They surely had the discussion who is the best. I'm quite sure they used the term, but it may be my memory playing tricks.
